# How to toggle between two Autohotkey configurations

Tags: autohotkey

I need to toggle between two AutoHotkey key mapping configurations.  I'd like to toggle the two through F3.  From my research online and on StackOverflow, I think the below should do what I want:

```
#ifwinactive

next_make_mac = %1%
msgbox next_make_mac: %next_make_mac%

#If next_make_mac
    msgbox Setting Mac settings.
    RAlt::Control
    Escape::Delete

    RWin::Escape
    LWin::LAlt
    LAlt::LWin
    next_make_mac := false
    msgbox Mac settings set.
#If

#If !next_make_mac
    msgbox Setting PC settings.
    Ralt::Escape
    msgbox PC settings set.
    next_make_mac := true
#If

msgbox %next_make_mac%

F3:: 
    Run %A_AhkPath% %A_ScriptName% %next_make_mac%
return
```

However, the `#If next_make_mac` directive always evaluates as true.  I'm not sure why this is.  In fact, even if I slip in a `next_make_mac := false` it still evaluates to true.  Is there a better way to do what I'm doing?

I'm running AutoHotkey 1.1.21.03

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, the message-boxes you have inside the `#If` statements will not behave as expected. The first one, on line 7 will always go off, telling you it's `Setting Mac settings`. Your hotkeys however, will be setup properly.

I think this is due to the auto-exec section reaching all the way to the first hotkey it finds.

Only put hotkeys inside `#If` statements.

---

Next, in your first `#If` statement, you're checking if `next_make_mac` contains anything *other* than `false` or `0`. Meaning the string `"false"`, will evaluate to true.

Note, `false` in AHK is the same as `0`.

In your second `#If` statement, you're checking if `next_make_mac` contains either `false` or `0`.

---

As for the toggling, since you can't change the values of variables directly inside `#If` statements, you'll have to add that to your <kbd>F3</kbd> hotkey.

Like this:

```
F3::
    next_make_mac := !next_make_mac ; Flip the value
    msgBox % next_make_mac
    Run %A_AhkPath% %A_ScriptName% %next_make_mac%
return
```

That line will toggle `next_make_mac`, assuming it contains either `true`, `false`, `1` or `0`.

---

So, make sure you only have hotkeys inside the `#If` statements, and pass `1` or `0` as params instead of `true` or `false` so you don't accidentally use a string, and your script should work as expected.

---

Here's a full example of the changes:

```
#SingleInstance, force
#ifwinactive

next_make_mac = %1%

; Check which settings we'll be using
if (next_make_mac)
    msgBox, Using Mac Settings
else
    msgBox, Using PC Settings

; Only hotkeys inside here
#If next_make_mac
    RAlt::Control
    Escape::Delete

    RWin::Escape
    LWin::LAlt
    LAlt::LWin
#If

; Only hotkeys inside here
#If !next_make_mac
    Ralt::Escape
#If

F3::
    next_make_mac := !next_make_mac ; Flip the value
    Run %A_AhkPath% %A_ScriptName% %next_make_mac%
return
```

**Edit**: While outside the scope of the question, you can also add `#SingleInstance, force` at the top of your script to get rid of that dialog that asks you if you want to restart the script every time you press <kbd>F3</kbd>.

Comment: Thank you Sidola!  Clearly I wasn't aware of this nature of the #If directive that prohibits setting variables inside of them.  Running your script seems to do what I want, so I'm accepting this answer.

Comment: @firebush Glad I could help. And just to be clear, you can run message-boxes and set variables inside `#If` directives, but only if you execute it via a hotkey. Otherwise the code is considered unreachable.

Answer (score 1):

```
OS:=["Mac","PC",""],i:=0

#If (map="Mac")
RAlt::Control
Escape::Delete
RWin::Escape
LWin::LAlt
LAlt::LWin

#If (map="PC")
Ralt::Escape

#If

F3::
 map:=OS[i:=i<os.MaxIndex()?++i:1]
 tooltip,% map,10000,10000
return
```

Comment: Mind to [explain your solution](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) a bit?